# generation of report

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm doing report line shift report I have 3 shifts:

```
shift1 starts at 7am and ends at 3pm
shift2 starts at 3pm and ends at 11pm
shift3 starts at 11pm and ends at 7am
```

I have to generate report based on shift. For example, if the user selects shift1 from dropdownlist the report should display all data from 7am to 3pm.

I'm able to fetch data for shift1 and shift2 but shift3 data I'm not able to fetch because
in shift3 after 12am the date will change.

So how to fetch data for shift3 and fetching data based on date in these 4 tables

my first table contains following data(shift3(11-7)):

```
Name       Shiftname     Operatorname  Date        plant    Line   Machine
---------  ------------  ------------  ----------  -------  -----  -------
Deepali    Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 1  Line1  mc1
Ashwini    Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 1  Line1  mc2
Antra      Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 1  Line2  mc3
Harshitha  Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 1  Line2  mc4
Pradeep    Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 2  Line3  mc5
Madhu      Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 2  Line3  mc6
Meena      Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 2  Line4  mc7
Suhas      Shift3(11-7)  Operator 3    2011-06-07  Plant 2  Line4  mc8
```

this is my temperature table (`shift3(11-7)`):

```
Temperature  Time                     Date
-----------  -----------------------  ----------
27           1900-01-01 23:34:56.000  2011-06-07
27.3         1900-01-01 23:36:56.000  2011-06-07
27.6         1900-01-01 23:38:56.000  2011-06-07
27.9         1900-01-01 23:40:56.000  2011-06-07
28.2         1900-01-01 23:42:56.000  2011-06-07
28.5         1900-01-01 23:44:55.000  2011-06-07
28.8         1900-01-01 23:46:55.000  2011-06-07
29.1         1900-01-01 23:48:55.000  2011-06-07
29.4         1900-01-01 23:50:55.000  2011-06-07
29.7         1900-01-01 23:52:55.000  2011-06-07
30           1900-01-01 23:54:55.000  2011-06-07
30           1900-01-01 23:56:55.000  2011-06-07
30.3         1900-01-01 23:58:55.000  2011-06-07
30.6         1900-01-01 00:00:55.000  2011-06-08
30.9         1900-01-01 00:02:55.000  2011-06-08
31.2         1900-01-01 00:04:55.000  2011-06-08
31.5         1900-01-01 00:06:55.000  2011-06-08
31.8         1900-01-01 00:08:55.000  2011-06-08
32.1         1900-01-01 00:10:55.000  2011-06-08
32.4         1900-01-01 00:12:55.000  2011-06-08
32.7         1900-01-01 00:14:55.000  2011-06-08
33           1900-01-01 00:16:55.000  2011-06-08
33.3         1900-01-01 00:18:55.000  2011-06-08
33.6         1900-01-01 00:20:55.000  2011-06-08
33.9         1900-01-01 00:22:55.000  2011-06-08
34.2         1900-01-01 00:24:55.000  2011-06-08
34.5         1900-01-01 00:26:55.000  2011-06-08
34.8         1900-01-01 00:28:55.000  2011-06-08
35.1         1900-01-01 00:30:55.000  2011-06-08
35.4         1900-01-01 00:32:55.000  2011-06-08
35.7         1900-01-01 00:34:55.000  2011-06-08
36           1900-01-01 00:36:55.000  2011-06-08
36.3         1900-01-01 00:38:55.000  2011-06-08
36.6         1900-01-01 00:40:55.000  2011-06-08
36.9         1900-01-01 00:42:55.000  2011-06-08
36.9         1900-01-01 00:44:55.000  2011-06-08
37.2         1900-01-01 00:46:55.000  2011-06-08
36.9         1900-01-01 00:48:55.000  2011-06-08
36.6         1900-01-01 00:50:55.000  2011-06-08
36.3         1900-01-01 00:52:55.000  2011-06-08
36           1900-01-01 00:54:55.000  2011-06-08
35.7         1900-01-01 00:56:55.000  2011-06-08
35.4         1900-01-01 00:58:55.000  2011-06-08
35.1         1900-01-01 01:00:55.000  2011-06-08
34.8         1900-01-01 01:02:55.000  2011-06-08
34.5         1900-01-01 01:04:55.000  2011-06-08
34.2         1900-01-01 01:06:55.000  2011-06-08
33.9         1900-01-01 01:08:55.000  2011-06-08
33.6         1900-01-01 01:10:55.000  2011-06-08
33.3         1900-01-01 01:12:55.000  2011-06-08
33           1900-01-01 01:14:55.000  2011-06-08
32.7         1900-01-01 01:16:55.000  2011-06-08
32.4         1900-01-01 01:18:55.000  2011-06-08
32.1         1900-01-01 01:20:55.000  2011-06-08
31.8         1900-01-01 01:22:55.000  2011-06-08
31.5         1900-01-01 01:24:55.000  2011-06-08
31.2         1900-01-01 01:26:55.000  2011-06-08
30.9         1900-01-01 01:28:55.000  2011-06-08
30.6         1900-01-01 01:30:55.000  2011-06-08
30.3         1900-01-01 01:32:56.000  2011-06-08
30           1900-01-01 01:34:55.000  2011-06-08
29.7         1900-01-01 01:36:56.000  2011-06-08
29.4         1900-01-01 01:38:55.000  2011-06-08
29.1         1900-01-01 01:40:55.000  2011-06-08
28.5         1900-01-01 03:03:02.000  2011-06-08
28.2         1900-01-01 03:05:02.000  2011-06-08
27.9         1900-01-01 03:07:02.000  2011-06-08
27.6         1900-01-01 03:09:02.000  2011-06-08
27.3         1900-01-01 03:11:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:13:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:15:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:17:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:19:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:21:03.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:23:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:25:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:27:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:29:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 04:33:06.000  2011-06-08
27.3         1900-01-01 04:35:07.000  2011-06-08
27.6         1900-01-01 04:37:06.000  2011-06-08
27.9         1900-01-01 04:39:07.000  2011-06-08
28.2         1900-01-01 04:41:06.000  2011-06-08
28.5         1900-01-01 04:43:06.000  2011-06-08
28.8         1900-01-01 04:45:06.000  2011-06-08
29.1         1900-01-01 04:47:07.000  2011-06-08
29.4         1900-01-01 04:49:06.000  2011-06-08
29.7         1900-01-01 04:51:06.000  2011-06-08
29.7         1900-01-01 04:53:06.000  2011-06-08
30           1900-01-01 04:55:06.000  2011-06-08
30.3         1900-01-01 04:57:06.000  2011-06-08
30.6         1900-01-01 04:59:07.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 05:33:04.000  2011-06-08
27.3         1900-01-01 05:35:04.000  2011-06-08
27.6         1900-01-01 05:37:04.000  2011-06-08
27.9         1900-01-01 05:39:04.000  2011-06-08
28.2         1900-01-01 05:41:04.000  2011-06-08
28.5         1900-01-01 05:43:04.000  2011-06-08
28.8         1900-01-01 05:45:04.000  2011-06-08
29.1         1900-01-01 05:47:04.000  2011-06-08
29.4         1900-01-01 05:49:04.000  2011-06-08
29.7         1900-01-01 05:51:04.000  2011-06-08
29.7         1900-01-01 05:53:04.000  2011-06-08
30           1900-01-01 05:55:04.000  2011-06-08
30.3         1900-01-01 05:57:04.000  2011-06-08
30.6         1900-01-01 05:59:04.000  2011-06-08
```

Same for pressure and ph, only pressure column and ph column value will be changed.

I'm storing data in database, there are 4 tables, date is my primary key in that.
I have to link those data based on date.

I'm displaying data in gridview.

I want my output like this:

```
Temperature  Time                     Date        Pressure
-----------  -----------------------  ----------  --------
27           1900-01-01 23:34:56.000  2011-06-07  30
27.3         1900-01-01 23:36:56.000  2011-06-07  30.1
27.6         1900-01-01 23:38:56.000  2011-06-07  30.2
27.9         1900-01-01 23:40:56.000  2011-06-07  30.3
28.2         1900-01-01 23:42:56.000  2011-06-07  30.4
28.5         1900-01-01 23:44:55.000  2011-06-07  30.5
28.8         1900-01-01 23:46:55.000  2011-06-07  30.6
29.1         1900-01-01 23:48:55.000  2011-06-07    .
29.4         1900-01-01 23:50:55.000  2011-06-07    .
29.7         1900-01-01 23:52:55.000  2011-06-07    .
30           1900-01-01 23:54:55.000  2011-06-07    .
30           1900-01-01 23:56:55.000  2011-06-07    .
30.3         1900-01-01 23:58:55.000  2011-06-07 
30.6         1900-01-01 00:00:55.000  2011-06-08 
30.9         1900-01-01 00:02:55.000  2011-06-08 
31.2         1900-01-01 00:04:55.000  2011-06-08 
31.5         1900-01-01 00:06:55.000  2011-06-08 
31.8         1900-01-01 00:08:55.000  2011-06-08 
32.1         1900-01-01 00:10:55.000  2011-06-08 
32.4         1900-01-01 00:12:55.000  2011-06-08 
32.7         1900-01-01 00:14:55.000  2011-06-08 
33           1900-01-01 00:16:55.000  2011-06-08 
33.3         1900-01-01 00:18:55.000  2011-06-08 
33.6         1900-01-01 00:20:55.000  2011-06-08 
33.9         1900-01-01 00:22:55.000  2011-06-08 
34.2         1900-01-01 00:24:55.000  2011-06-08 
34.5         1900-01-01 00:26:55.000  2011-06-08 
34.8         1900-01-01 00:28:55.000  2011-06-08 
35.1         1900-01-01 00:30:55.000  2011-06-08 
35.4         1900-01-01 00:32:55.000  2011-06-08 
35.7         1900-01-01 00:34:55.000  2011-06-08 
36           1900-01-01 00:36:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.3         1900-01-01 00:38:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.6         1900-01-01 00:40:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.9         1900-01-01 00:42:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.9         1900-01-01 00:44:55.000  2011-06-08 
37.2         1900-01-01 00:46:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.9         1900-01-01 00:48:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.6         1900-01-01 00:50:55.000  2011-06-08 
36.3         1900-01-01 00:52:55.000  2011-06-08 
36           1900-01-01 00:54:55.000  2011-06-08 
35.7         1900-01-01 00:56:55.000  2011-06-08 
35.4         1900-01-01 00:58:55.000  2011-06-08 
35.1         1900-01-01 01:00:55.000  2011-06-08 
34.8         1900-01-01 01:02:55.000  2011-06-08 
34.5         1900-01-01 01:04:55.000  2011-06-08 
34.2         1900-01-01 01:06:55.000  2011-06-08 
33.9         1900-01-01 01:08:55.000  2011-06-08 
33.6         1900-01-01 01:10:55.000  2011-06-08 
33.3         1900-01-01 01:12:55.000  2011-06-08 
33           1900-01-01 01:14:55.000  2011-06-08 
32.7         1900-01-01 01:16:55.000  2011-06-08 
32.4         1900-01-01 01:18:55.000  2011-06-08 
32.1         1900-01-01 01:20:55.000  2011-06-08 
31.8         1900-01-01 01:22:55.000  2011-06-08 
31.5         1900-01-01 01:24:55.000  2011-06-08 
31.2         1900-01-01 01:26:55.000  2011-06-08 
30.9         1900-01-01 01:28:55.000  2011-06-08 
30.6         1900-01-01 01:30:55.000  2011-06-08 
30.3         1900-01-01 01:32:56.000  2011-06-08 
30           1900-01-01 01:34:55.000  2011-06-08 
29.7         1900-01-01 01:36:56.000  2011-06-08 
29.4         1900-01-01 01:38:55.000  2011-06-08 
29.1         1900-01-01 01:40:55.000  2011-06-08 
28.5         1900-01-01 03:03:02.000  2011-06-08 
28.2         1900-01-01 03:05:02.000  2011-06-08 
27.9         1900-01-01 03:07:02.000  2011-06-08 
27.6         1900-01-01 03:09:02.000  2011-06-08 
27.3         1900-01-01 03:11:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:13:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:15:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:17:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:19:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:21:03.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:23:02.000  2011-06-08
27           1900-01-01 03:25:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:27:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 03:29:02.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 04:33:06.000  2011-06-08 
27.3         1900-01-01 04:35:07.000  2011-06-08 
27.6         1900-01-01 04:37:06.000  2011-06-08 
27.9         1900-01-01 04:39:07.000  2011-06-08 
28.2         1900-01-01 04:41:06.000  2011-06-08 
28.5         1900-01-01 04:43:06.000  2011-06-08 
28.8         1900-01-01 04:45:06.000  2011-06-08 
29.1         1900-01-01 04:47:07.000  2011-06-08 
29.4         1900-01-01 04:49:06.000  2011-06-08 
29.7         1900-01-01 04:51:06.000  2011-06-08 
29.7         1900-01-01 04:53:06.000  2011-06-08 
30           1900-01-01 04:55:06.000  2011-06-08 
30.3         1900-01-01 04:57:06.000  2011-06-08 
30.6         1900-01-01 04:59:07.000  2011-06-08 
27           1900-01-01 05:33:04.000  2011-06-08 
27.3         1900-01-01 05:35:04.000  2011-06-08 
27.6         1900-01-01 05:37:04.000  2011-06-08 
27.9         1900-01-01 05:39:04.000  2011-06-08 
28.2         1900-01-01 05:41:04.000  2011-06-08 
28.5         1900-01-01 05:43:04.000  2011-06-08 
28.8         1900-01-01 05:45:04.000  2011-06-08 
29.1         1900-01-01 05:47:04.000  2011-06-08 
29.4         1900-01-01 05:49:04.000  2011-06-08 
29.7         1900-01-01 05:51:04.000  2011-06-08 
29.7         1900-01-01 05:53:04.000  2011-06-08 
30           1900-01-01 05:55:04.000  2011-06-08 
30.3         1900-01-01 05:57:04.000  2011-06-08
30.6         1900-01-01 05:59:04.000  2011-06-08    .
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It seems like you are asking two questions.  The first one has something to do with shifs and the second something to do with different values.  Ask only one question and make another SO question for the 2nd question.

Comment: @Hogan-no this only my question..

Comment: Then you have to make the question clearer or you won't get any helpful responses.  See this link [ask]

Comment: @Hogan-K from next time onwards i will ask clearly..

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the requirements -- when someone selects shift 3 and a date they can mean 3 different things:

- Report on shift 3s that start on that date.
- Report on shift 3s that end on that date.
- Report on the shift 3s from midnight to 7am and 11 to midnight on that date.

If people are really getting reports by date then I would expect they would want the last one.

Comment: @Hogan-i want the third one.   .Report on the shift3 from midnight to 7am and 11 to midnight on that date.

Comment: @Sweety Then it is easy because the date does not change... now what is your question?

Comment: @Hogan-how come date will not change its taking system date i have shown no i want output like that

Comment: @Sweety -- that is the point of the 3rd option above.  The two parts of two different shifts that occurred on the same day - thus the date won't change.  If you want one of the others then the shift will start and end on different dates.  BUT THIS DOES NOT MAKE SENSE TO ME because you are asking for a report for a particular day.  This is why you need to FIND OUT THE REQUIREMENTS.

Comment: @Hogan-Report on the shift3 from that date 11pm to 12am and shift3 midnight to next day morning 7am.

Comment: @Sweety then you would want the first option not the third option in my list.  In my experience working with business logic I've had to solve this problem twice, in both cases they wanted the 3rd option.  I would check with the requirements and make sure.  It is also possible (and even likely) the client does not realize what they are asking for here.  Point out the edge case where on the last day of a billing cycle you would be including time for the next billing cycle in the report.  I expect their eyes will open wide and they will pick the 3rd option.

Comment: @Sweety - I've given up on answering your question -- in both of my suggestions you told me I was wrong.  I've made my point clear.  Read everything on [ask], post a new question or revise this on and then I might help.  I spent to much time on this question for someone who tells me I'm wrong.